# mysql and vb6-stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, vb6

Hello I have the following code below...

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `gateshms`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `SP_Rank_by_Company`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`gates`@`%` PROCEDURE `SP_Rank_by_Company`(PETSA VARCHAR(50),ins VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
    IF ins = "DELETE" THEN

        DELETE FROM tblrevrankreport WHERE xdate = PETSA;

    ELSEIF ins = "INSERT" THEN

        INSERT INTO tblrevrankreport (ndate, xDate, tid, transid, rmno, rmcat, rmcatdesc, rmtariff,
            marketdesc, cindate, coutdate, 
            mulrate,
            revamt,
            othamt,
            Company) 
        SELECT a.xDate, a.xDate, b.id, a.guestno, a.roomno, b.RoomCat, b.roomcat, b.Room_Tariff,
            b.Market, b.CInDate, b.coutdate, 
            b.MultipleRate,
            IF(c.ratecode=1,(a.amount-(a.AMT_VAT+a.AMT_SC+a.AMT_LT)),''),
            IF(c.ratecode<>1,(a.amount-(a.AMT_VAT+a.AMT_SC+a.AMT_LT)),''),b.Company
            FROM  tbltransactionpostingdumy a 
            LEFT JOIN tblcustomerinfo b ON a.MaintransNo = b.transactionID
            LEFT JOIN tblreftransaction c ON a.trcode = c.xcode
            WHERE a.xDate = PETSA AND c.xcat = 'ROOM CHARGE';

    ELSEIF ins = "UPDATE_NNN1" THEN

        UPDATE  tblrevrankreport tr INNER JOIN tblcustomerinfohistory tc
            ON tr.xDate = tc.xDate
                AND tr.`transid` = tc.`TransactionID` 
                AND tr.`xDate` = PETSA
                AND tr.COutDate > tr.xdate 
                AND (tr.rmcat <> 'PQ' OR tr.rmcat <> 'Walkin')
        SET tr.nyts = 1,
            tr.NoOfAdult = tc.NoOfAdult,
            tr.NoOfChild = tc.NoOfChild;

    ELSEIF ins = "UPDATE_NNN2" THEN

        UPDATE tblrevrankreport
        SET   
            nyts = '0', 
            NoOfAdult = '0', 
            NoOfChild = '0'
        WHERE xdate = PETSA
            AND coutdate<=xdate;

    ELSEIF ins = "UPDATE_ROOMTARIFFDESC" THEN

        UPDATE tblrevrankreport,tblroomrate
        SET tblrevrankreport.`rmtariffdesc` = tblroomrate.`rateDesc`
        WHERE tblrevrankreport.rmtariff = tblroomrate.`room_type` 
        AND tblrevrankreport.xdate = PETSA;

    ELSEIF ins = "UPDATE_ROOMDESC" THEN

        UPDATE tblrevrankreport,tblroom
        SET tblrevrankreport.`rmdesc` = tblroom.`roomdesc`
        WHERE tblrevrankreport.`rmno` = tblroom.`Room_No`
        AND tblrevrankreport.xdate = PETSA;

    ELSEIF ins = "UPDATE_MARKETCODE" THEN

        UPDATE tblrevrankreport,tblcmarket
        SET tblrevrankreport.marketCode = tblcmarket.`xCode`
        WHERE tblcmarket.`xDesc` = tblrevrankreport.`marketdesc`
        AND tblrevrankreport.xdate = PETSA;
    END IF;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

For a certain report, since i can't add a progress bar during the procedure is running (It will lead the application to be not responding) I added a variable named "ins" just to cut the whole procedure per query then add a certain ui manipulation in between it, see the code below:

```
Public Sub processRevRank(ByVal MyDate1 As String, ByVal MyDate2 As String)

    '-- LATEST CODE AS OF JUNE 08, 2017
    Dim RSC As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = Format(MyDate1, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    Dim xDays As Integer
    If MyDate1 = "" And MyDate2 <> "" Then
        MyDate2 = MyDate1
        xDays = DateDiff("d", MyDate2, MyDate2)
    ElseIf MyDate1 <> "" And MyDate2 = "" Then
        MyDate1 = MyDate2
        xDays = DateDiff("d", MyDate1, MyDate1)
    ElseIf MyDate1 <> "" And MyDate2 <> "" Then
        xDays = DateDiff("d", MyDate1, MyDate2)
    Else
        Unload frmLoadingReports
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim xWidth As Integer
    If xDays <> 0 Then
        xWidth = 886 / xDays
    Else
        xWidth = 886
    End If

    Do Until CDate(sDate) > CDate(MyDate2)
        frmLoadingReports.lblTitle.Caption = "PROCESSING ( Rank by Company : " & sDate & " )"

        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleBack.Caption = "Deleting Records"
        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleFront.Caption = "Deleting Records"
        frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width + xWidth
        DoEvents

        Set RSC = Nothing
        Set RSC = OpenRS("CALL SP_Rank_by_Company('" & sDate & "','DELETE')")

        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleBack.Caption = "Inserting Records"
        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleFront.Caption = "Inserting Records"
        frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width + xWidth
        DoEvents

        Set RSC = Nothing
        Set RSC = OpenRS("CALL SP_Rank_by_Company('" & sDate & "','INSERT')")

        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleBack.Caption = "Updating Records"
        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleFront.Caption = "Updating Records"
        frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width + xWidth
        DoEvents

        Set RSC = Nothing
        Set RSC = OpenRS("CALL SP_Rank_by_Company('" & sDate & "','UPDATE_NNN1')")

        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleBack.Caption = "Updating Room Tariff Description"
        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleFront.Caption = "Updating Room Tariff Description"
        frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width + xWidth
        DoEvents

        Set RSC = Nothing
        Set RSC = OpenRS("CALL SP_Rank_by_Company('" & sDate & "','UPDATE_ROOMTARIFFDESC')")

        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleBack.Caption = "Updating Room Description"
        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleFront.Caption = "Updating Room Description"
        frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width + xWidth
        DoEvents

        Set RSC = Nothing
        Set RSC = OpenRS("CALL SP_Rank_by_Company('" & sDate & "','UPDATE_ROOMDESC')")

        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleBack.Caption = "Updating Marketcode"
        frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleFront.Caption = "Updating Marketcode"
        frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width + xWidth
        DoEvents

        Set RSC = Nothing
        Set RSC = OpenRS("CALL SP_Rank_by_Company('" & sDate & "','UPDATE_MARKETCODE')")

        sDate = DateAdd("d", 1, MyDate1)
        sDate = Format(sDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    Loop

    frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleBack.Caption = "Done"
    frmLoadingReports.lblLoadingTitleFront.Caption = "Done"
    frmLoadingReports.picLoading.Width = 5320
    DoEvents

    'timer for closing
    frmLoadingReports.Timer4.Enabled = True

    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I'm still not satisfied since the not responding still occurs, I'm thinking of cutting the UPDATE part in the query since the ui hangs in that part by transaction and by date.

My question is...
How can I make a stored procedure with SELECT table1 on it, then use the selected records to UPDATE table2 and loop it until a certain condition is satisfied? Any simple sql stored procedure that loops select and update?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than trying to fix this in the UI (or as a first step), have you satisfied yourself that the database is tuned to run these queries as efficiently as possible?

Comment: Yes, got it, that was the case, I was running the project in vmware using WinXP. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to fix this in the UI (or as a first step), have you satisfied yourself that the database is tuned to run these queries as efficiently as possible?